# How to get all types of file extensions in array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macos

How to get all types of file extensions which supports the `macOS` or `iOS`?
I am statically defining the `extensions` as below, but I don't wanna do in this way.
 If Apple introduces the new `extension` i should get dynamically all the `extensions`. how to achieve this?

```
let fileExtensions = ["png", "jpg", "gif","jpeg","tif","mp4","mkv","mov", "zip" ,"txz"]
```

Any Suggestions?

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: The Array approach is correct, apple does not introduces file extensions, file extensions are introduced by new applications, using MIME types a user or application on macOS can associate file extension with an application

Comment: I recommend you start by learning about UTIs from [Uniform Type Identifiers Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html). There's probably some API that lets you list all registered UTIs, from which you can then access all registered extensions. I can't seem to find it right now though